# Is there a way to check the permissions of a role in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I would like to know if there is any way to get the permissions of a role in discord.js. I have a command that adds a role to a user that works by mentioning a user and a role, and I need to check whether or not the role mentioned has the Administrator permission. This is to prevent people with low permission levels from giving themselves roles with Administrator permissions.

Comment: Yes: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=permissions

Answer (score 0):

I have that feeling, that the Discord.js docs will be your next best friend: [`Permissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions) is the Collection you're looking for :)

Let me give you a quick example. Let's say we want to know if the author can manage messages (selecting their highest role):

```js
const manageMessages = message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES") // boolean
```

Or for a specific role, as you asked:

```js
const roleCanManageMessages = role.permissions.has('MANAGE_MESSAGES')
```

You can find the string for each perm [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS), but keep in mind that this isn't the only way to know whether or not a member has a perm.